# Caliburn.Micro: Communication between user controls

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm building my first Caliburn WPF application, and I find myself in the following problem.

I have a parent view, with loads two user controls: Search & Results. When the search button is clicked on the Search user control, I wan't to load the results in the results user control.

**Parent View:**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="SearchViewModel"/>
<ContentControl x:Name="ResultsViewModel"/>
```

**Parent VM**

```
[Export(typeof(IMainViewModel))]
public class ParentViewModel : Screen, IMainViewModel{

public SearchViewModel SearchViewModel { get; set; }
public ResultsViewModel ResultsViewModel { get; set; }
public ParentViewModel()
{
    SearchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();
    ResultsViewModel = new ResultsViewModel();
}
}
```

**Search View**

```
<TextBox x:Name="Term"/>        
<Button Content="Search" x:Name="Search"/>
```

**Search VM**

```
public class SearchViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
        private string _term;

        public string Term
        {
            get { return _term; }
            set
            {
                _instrumentId = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => _term);
            }
        }

        public void Search()
        {
            //Call WCF Service
            //Send results to results user control?
        }
}
```

**So actually how can i pass or access data/methods between different user controls / view models with caliburn micro?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use events via the [Caliburn Micro Event Aggregator](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2011/05/30/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-8-the-eventaggregator.aspx). You can publish an event in one viewmodel and subscribe that event in the other. This keep the model decoupled - the only coupling is done by the event itself-, in which you can store the data to transfer.